# How can I layer these div tags?

Tags: css

I've written some javascript that first loads an image into div1a, div2a, div3a and div4a.
Then it sequentially loads the "b" divs and fades out the "a" divs.

What I want is for the "b" divs to fade in over top of the "a" divs before the "a" divs fade out.

The javascript is working fine except for the fact that the "b" divs load below instead of on top of the "a" divs.

Keep in mind that this table is inside a centered "wrapper" div. So, using absolute positioning doesn't seem to work.

```
<table height="258" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="244">
      <div id="div1a" style="position:relative; z-index:100;">HERE</div>
      <div id="div1b" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:101">THERE</div>
    </td>
    <td width="244">
      <div id="div2a" style="position:relative;"></div>
      <div id="div2b" style="position:relative;"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="244">
      <div id="div3a" style="position:relative;"></div>
      <div id="div3b" style="position:relative;"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="244">
      <div id="div4a" style="position:relative;"></div>
      <div id="div4b" style="position:relative;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: its because your positions are all set to relative. What do you mean using absolute positioning doesn't seem to work? what have you tried.

Comment: I've tried positioning the "b" divs at absolute. But, that just causes them to show up in the upper right hand corner of the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, maybe using `position: relative` on the parent and `position: absolute` would work:

```
<table height="258" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="244" style="position:relative;">
      <div id="div1a" style="position:absolute; z-index:100;">HERE</div>
      <div id="div1b" style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:101">THERE</div>
    </td>
    <td width="244" style="position:relative;">
      <div id="div2a" style="position:absolute;"></div>
      <div id="div2b" style="position:absolute;"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="244" style="position:relative;">
      <div id="div3a" style="position:absolute;"></div>
      <div id="div3b" style="position:absolute;"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="244" style="position:relative;">
      <div id="div4a" style="position:absolute;"></div>
      <div id="div4b" style="position:absolute;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: posisiton:absolute causes the "b" div to show up in the upper left had corner of the entire page.

Comment: Blender,
I didn't look at your code. (Shame on me!)
That works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can then mark this as the answer, as others with the same problem will know that this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make your containers ( here) position:relative.  Make both of the s in side "position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;".  No z-index should be necessary.

Comment: Is this what you mean?

    <div id="div1a" style="position:relative; z-index:1;">HERE</div>
    <div id="div1b" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:2">THERE</div>

That makes the "b" div show up in the upper left hand corner of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but I would highly recommend looking at http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ to accomplish what you're doing. It sounds like you could very easily get the interaction you're looking for.

Either way, best wishes!

Comment: That would be perfect, except my divs also include text and both the text and image contain links.

Comment: Not a problem. You can target any DOM element, including a DIV. So you could simply wrap each set of images, text, and links (positioned and styled as you wish) in a div then target that set of divs.